# Catching button presses from many rows (Shopping Cart) with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm coding a shopping cart type functionality where I am querying a database for a number of items (SKU, qty, name) in an $(.ajax) call. I'd like to display a table with all the items that match what the user is looking for, with the option where the user can specify a quantity desired. They can then click an 'Add' to add their selection to a "cart".

Here's a simplified example:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Item A</td><td>SKU: 001</td><td>Qty: <input name="qty-sku001"> <input type="button" value="Add"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item B</td><td>SKU: 002</td><td>Qty: <input name="qty-sku002"> <input type="button" value="Add"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item C</td><td>SKU: 003</td><td>Qty: <input name="qty-sku003"> <input type="button" value="Add"></td></tr>
</table>
```

What is the ideal way to get information from just one row, when it's button is clicked?
I was thinking of adding an onclick="AddToCart(x);" to each button, but that'd just pass in an HTML Form Element object. Do I need to make each row it's own form, or can I get the button's parent TR and then grab the values from that row's input and other elements?

The data will end up being appended to a "Cart" div's table, so I'll need the three pieces of data I loaded in from my ajax call. I suppose I can add hidden elements to each row, but there must be a more efficient and graceful solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you use jQuery, you can use this:

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function(evn){
    var rowName = $(this).prev().attr('name'); // this will give you the name attribute of element that is before the button in the DOM

    // do here whatever you need with rowName
});
```

**edit**

you can add a class to buttons to prevent running this code for all buttons on your page like this:

```
<input class="row-button" type="button" value="Add">
```

and use this javascript:

```
$(".row-button").click(function(evn){
    // the code from above
}
```

Comment: Funny thing is, I can't select these buttons at all. They are dynamically created in the success function of an ajax call, which is made from within a set of jquery tabs. I think maybe the tabs or the ajax object's calls are causing an issue, as they do show up in the DOM when I introspect the page. I tried binding the click function as you've shown above, but the function is never reached.

Comment: have you tried to bind this function at the end of your `success` callback? because as these buttons are created in callback of ajax, the binding should be called after their creation

Comment: Thanks, Haynar. I'll go back and give that another try. In the interim, I added an 'onclick' to each button and that worked, but I didn't like all the extra code involved.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input:button").click(function(){var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');});
```

$tr is the jquery row object that a button has been clicked

Comment: Thanks, Frenchi. the 'closest' selector was very helpful and cleaner than .parent().parent().